# Jquery .change function not running SQL select statement when passing variable with spaces

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, sql

I have two drop down lists both populated from a SQL database. The second drop down list is populated according to what the user selects from the first drop down list.

The second drop down list will only populate if the value selected in the first drop down list contains NO SPACES. If the first drop lists selected value contains spaces then nothing is displayed in the second drop down list.

Im using a jquery. change function that loads up 'getter.php' that runs a SQL select statement that performs a where clause against the value selected in the first drop down list.

My aim is to get any value that is selected in the first drop list that contains spaces to allow the second drop list to be populated according to that value.

Thanks in advance!

test.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php

include 'connect.php';

?>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
<title> Test </title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#db-one").change(function() {
                $("#db-two").load("getter.php?choice=" + $("#db-one").val());
            });

        });
    </script>


</head>
<body>


<?php
$query = "SELECT parent FROM poc_sla GROUP BY Parent"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
?>


<select name="db-one" id="db-one" style="width:400px;">

<option value="">--Select--</option>

<?php
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
?> 

<option value="<?php echo $line['parent'];?>"> <?php echo $line['parent'];?> </option>

<?php
}
?>


</select> 


<br>

<select id="db-two">
  <option>Please choose from above</option>
</select>


</body>
</html>
```

getter.php

```
<?php



    $dbhandle = mysql_connect("localhost", "test", "test") or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
    $selected = mysql_select_db("problemmanagement") or die("Could not select examples");
    $choice = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['choice']);

    $query = "SELECT subsidiary FROM poc_sla WHERE Parent ='$choice'";


    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<option>" . $row{'subsidiary'} . "</option>";
        //echo "<option>" . $query . "</option>";

    }
?>
```

Comment: So You are saying it does not work if you have `WHERE Parent ='word1 word2'"` ? Or is it the mysql_real_escape_string that inserts something instead of space or + or %20?

Comment: For example if in the first drop list i select "COLOR" it would load the variable $choice with "COLOR" and the second drop down list would populate with "RED" for example.

Comment: But if the value i selected in the first drop down was "COLOR SHADE" the second drop down would not populate as their is a space in between COLOR and SHADE. Hope that makes more sense cheers

Comment: Did you see what was ACTUALLY requested in the DB and what is returned? For example COLOR%20SHADE will likely not be in your DB

Comment: so ive tried this.. $choice = urldecode(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['choice']));

Comment: However i seem to think the error lies within the jquery code before it even gets to the getter.php file ?

Comment: can you perhaps look at the request sent and what is received and what is it decoded to? Better than guessing. Also post the HTML rendered instead of the php

Comment: Ive found that the value is loaded into the javascript by using document.write( $("#db-one").val()); and this is correct.

Comment: Ive found that just manaually placing the value into the option value in the getter.php with all other code commented.  Still does not work. There seems to something stopping getter.php running at all when there are spaces in the first drop down

Comment: Check your network tab to see what is actually send.

Comment: Hi guys ive just opened up the developer tools and it shows that only the first word is being passed to getter.php so for example selecting the value 'COLOR SHADE' only 'COLOR' is being passed. –

Comment: Please post the VIEW-SOURCE of the select. You have `<option value="<?php echo $line['parent'];?>">` but if there is a newline it will also only send the first part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working! I just needed to add encodeURIComponent**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $("#db-one").change(function() {
                $("#db-two").load("getter.php?choice=" + encodeURIComponent($("#db-one").val()));

                });

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your url is not encoded, spaces are replaced with %20

Try :

```
$("#db-two").load("getter.php",
{
    choice : $("#db-one").val()
});
```

Comment: just tried this same error, and also does not allow words with no spaces through either

Answer (score -1):

Try this .It should work

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
      var value = $('#db-one').val();
      value = value.replace(' ', ''); // replace white space
      $("#db-one").change(function() {
           $("#db-two").load("getter.php?choice="+value);
      });

     });
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply ive just tried this and still the same error

Comment: Still no joy im afraid. I seem to think the problem is within the jquery rather than the code in the getter.php

Comment: echo your $choice variable and check what you are getting.

Comment: ive tried echoing choice but as the getter.php will not run when a value with spaces is selected i cannot see what is being output.

Comment: use ajax post instead of .load in test.php which will send all data to getter.php and in getter.php use above code which will work fine for you.

Comment: how do you use ajax post, not used that before?

Comment: I have posted sollution Please find it.

Comment: Use `trim` also on the client side. Otherwise `%20` or other encoded characters will not be trimmed by PHP

Comment: just tried using ajax and also does not work im afraid cheers

Comment: Please remove $_GET and use _POST to get ajax response.

Comment: @NileshBhanushali this is not the main problem. The OP has to open his developer tools and check what is send via the network tab.

Comment: Hi guys ive just opened up the developer tools and it shows that only the first word is being passed to getter.php so for example selecting the value 'COLOR SHADE' only 'COLOR' is being passed.

Comment: Hi nilesh that doesn't seem to work, i monitored using developer tools and it does not pass any variable